# Problem loading a flat file into a data frame from Azure Data Lake

Tags: python, pandas, azure, dataframe

I wrote Python to load data from Azure Data Lake into a data frame for processing.  I have two file types (CSV and flat files).  The CSV loads without a problem, but the flat file errors out.

I know it is an issue with the file format.  It gives a type error: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I cannot figure out how to convert the file to make it work properly.  Ive tried encoding and decoding, but I ran into an attribute error : 'AzureDLFile' object has no attribute 'decode'

When I tested the script locally on my C:\ drive it works fine, so I suspect the file coming out of Azure is different.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to convert the file so I can bring it in?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os

from azure.datalake.store import core, lib, multithread

USERNAME = "xxxx"
PASSWORD = "xxxx"
TENANT_ID = "xxxx"
STORE_NAME = "xxxx"

token = lib.auth(TENANT_ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
adl = core.AzureDLFileSystem(token, store_name=STORE_NAME)

#EXAMPLE 1 - OPENING A CSV FILE INTO A DATA FRAME - WORKS FINE
f = adl.open('/path/filename1.txt')
df = pd.read_csv(f,dtype=str, sep='|')
df[:3]

#EXAMPLE 2 - OPENING A FLAT FIXED WIDTH FILE INTO A DATA FRAME - DOES NOT WORK
f1 = adl.open('/path/filename2') #THIS FILE HAS NO EXTENSION
df2 = pd.read_fwf(f1)
df2[:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Key is converting the dataframe to a string and than using the str.encode() function.

Try something like below

```
adl = core.AzureDLFileSystem(token, store_name='YOUR_ADLS_STORE_NAME')
      #toke is your login token that was created by whatever ADLS login method you decided.
      #Personally I use the ServiceProvider login
df_str = df.to_csv()
**with adl.open('/path/to/file/on/adls/newfile.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(str.encode(df_str))
    f.close()**
```

Hope it helps.